# Problems installing firebase on Android side of things

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I'm trying to install the firebase plugin, but lately I've been getting an error which prevents me from correctly installing it.
I am getting the following error:
`Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (23.0.0) and test app (25.4.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.`
I tried changing the version for `com.android.support:support-annotations` to `23.0.0` but that just gives me this error:
`Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (23.0.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.`
Any one who has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your `app` level `gradle` file with the following.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
[...]

compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0'
}
```

Still facing issue then try adding this in your 'gradle'

```
 configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
 }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the versions match, the number's should be exactly same (eg. **Resolved versions for app (23.1.1) and test app (23.1.1)**). It will be great if you add an image of the error.

Comment: Where exactly should I change this? Sorry for the late response!

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have a look @BramVanbilsen

Comment: Awesome, just adding `compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0'` worked! Is there any reason why it didn't work automatically? Am I running a wrong version of something perhaps? Because, I'd love to know why this problem actually occurred. Could you clarify that a bit more? That'd make the answer check mark worthy!

Comment: I think there is an bug in Android Studio. You may refer to the following link for more details
 [link](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Resolving-conflicts-between-main-and-test-APK) 
**When instrumentation tests are run, both the main APK and test APK share the same classpath. Gradle build will fail if the main APK and the test APK use the same library (e.g. Guava) but in different versions. If gradle didn't catch that, your app could behave differently during tests and during normal run (including crashing in one of the cases).**

Comment: I hope you get the issue, If you are satisfied then please accept the answer. Thank you.